# Delete data from table made with php echo?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, sql-delete

I have an html table made with PHP code, like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['name'];
    echo "<a href = "DELETE.php" "...>Delete</a> "
```

and I want to delete that value where the link is; so.. I know how to delete data from sql tables and all that stuff, the question is how to store the `$row['name']` variable to delete it (with Delete.php file).

Comment: is `$row['name']` unique? If yes you could do this: `echo '<a href="DELETE.php?name=' . $row['name'] . '">Delete</a>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intent is to delete the row, then fetch the id not the name:

In your loop:

```
echo "<a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a>";
```

Then in `delete.php`:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = ?';
    $delete = $con->prepare($sql);
    $delete->bind_param('i', $id);
    $delete->execute();

    if($delete->affected_rows > 0) {
        header('Location: back_to_that_page.php');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'm a little new and I didn't think in that option , now it's working..